# How can I restore Firefox windows?

Tags: firefox

I had three Firefox windows, each with a few tabs. One of them also had a “restore previous session” tab which I was planning to open once I had dealt with and closed all of the current tabs. I hit ... something (I’m really not sure what I did: I think I did something with the keyboard while the wrong window was in focus), and suddenly two of the windows (including the one containing the previous session) disappeared. The “Recently closed windows” under the History menu is greyed out: there is no sign of these two windows anywhere. What happened, and is there any way to get them back short of manually going through my entire history of all visited pages for the past week and a half?

I did grab a copy of my `~/.mozilla` folder, but I don’t know how to read it. I’m capable of parsing JSON if that’s necessary, but I’d rather not.

Comment: You could use the history function, but `ctrl` + `shift` + `t` is the shortcut for reopening the most recently closed tab/window.

Answer (score 1):

From your `~/.mozilla` folder find the file named `places.sqlite`

Open it with DB Browser. Go to `Browse Data` tab and choose `moz_places` table.

To install DB Browser for SQLite (http://sqlitebrowser.org/):

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Session Manager, it gives you the ability to save different sessions in different windows and much more options:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/

Comment: That doesn't actually solve my current problem, does it? It might possibly stop this happening again, I suppose.

Comment: that is correct, it doesn't fix your actual problem but helps for the future...for your actual problem, did you looked at mozilla support page?

perhaps this could help? https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/1088713